# How to use JavaScript within a Django template?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I have created a JS file in my project and created this method:

```
function changeValue() {
        document.getElementById("change-paragraph").value = "Changed";
}
```

In my template I have this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeValue()">Click to change</button>

<p id="change-paragraph">Not changed</p>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens? This template extends my base.html file which includes this to use the JS method:

```
<script src="{% static 'games/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Nothing to do with Django. `p` elements don't have a `value` attribute; you mean `textContent`.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that, TIL. Thank you.